# Boot and run OS/2 1.x from floppy to run a few command-line tools

Tags: boot, os2

How (by doing which steps) can I boot and run OS/2 1.x from a boot floppy, without installing it to a hard drive? As a way to do this, is it possible to go to the command prompt from within the installer?

I only need to run a few command-line tools, which are on another floppy disk, in the second floppy drive.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

On OS/2 1.0, it's possible to boot from the *programs* floppy, which gives a command prompt after a few seconds.

On OS/2 Warp 4.0, it's possible to boot from the *install* floppy (and then swap floppies as asked 2 times), and then there will be a blue screen with its bottom line indicating that pressing *F3* opens a command prompt. Doing so indeed does it. (Please note, however, that this command prompt is not able to execute OS/2 1.x programs, because they are 16-bit, and it can execute only 32-bit.)

I wasn't able to try the installers of OS/2 1.1, 1.2 or 1.3, because they hang in my QEMU.